# How to uninstall an app from the list of installed apps using React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to uninstall an app from the list of installed apps using *React Native*? Does it require permission?

I can check the app using this library, but how would I uninstall.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-check-app-install